# Automated Drawing with logic inside of paintComponent() not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I have spent the last couple days trying to learn about 2D graphics in java, and I'm starting to get the hang of it. I went through a tutorial, and I now understand how to draw lines (or other objects) to a `JFrame`. However, I've hit a mental roadblock. I want to create a grid on the frame, and I've embedded the necessary logic into the `paintComponent()` section of the code, but it doesn't work. I know I could simply write `drawLine()` over and over, but why doesn't the code work if I add in the commented sections?

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Line Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public int x = 50;

public MyPanel() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(250,250);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       

    //while(x<250){
    g.drawLine(0,x,250,x);
    g.drawLine(x,0,x,250);
    //x = x+50;}
}  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake :) You need to set x to 50 before the loop, because the `paintComponent` often gets ran multiple times. Your grid works the first render (at least for me), but when it runs the second frame/render the x is already 250. Your code should be this:

```
x = 50;
while(x<250){
g.drawLine(0,x,250,x);
g.drawLine(x,0,x,250);
x = x+50;}
```

Hope this was helpfull :)